# Django user creation with costume boostrap form

Tags: django, django-forms

I know how to create and extend a usercreation form using the Django modelsform.

But how can I create and authenticate a user without using the inbuilt Django form instead i will use a bootstrap form having my own tailored designs and additional fields?

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue i  had to use django-widget-tweaks to modify my interfaces. it is really a good Django package